# La brioche, la croûte de pâté et la piquette : gradation de connotations, comparaisons ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, histoire, alimentation, connotation

Avant la fin temporaire de la paralysie partielle de l'état fédéral américain (« shutdown »), un parvenu de fils à papa (M. Wilbur Ross) a tenu certains [propos](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201901/24/01-5212317-le-gouvernement-trump-accuse-de-manquer-dempathie.php) qui lui ont valu une réponse, entre autres de la part de la présidente de la Chambre des représentants, Mme Nancy Pelosi, référant par analogie à une phrase probablement attribuée à tort à la reine Marie-Antoinette d'Autriche au moment de la famine précédant les évènements de 1789 ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu'ils_mangent_de_la_brioche))<sup>1</sup> :

> [S'ils n'ont pas de pain,] **[q]u'ils mangent de la brioche !** [*Let them
>   eat cake!*]

Indépendamment de l'attribution et de son contexte, il n'en reste pas moins que ces propos réfèrent aujourd'hui à une attitude de dédain, méprisante, envers le moins nantis, « censée illustrer la distance sociale qui existait entre les classes populaires et la noblesse » ; on dit aussi que « cette viennoiserie est encore plus onéreuse que le pain » (Wikipédia). Par ailleurs, un sens familier et vieilli de [*brioche*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brioche) est une « bévue » (TLFi ; pas de mention *vieilli* au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brioche)).

Avec le vin, on a la [*piquette*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/piquette/1), par analogie avec une boisson à laquelle on ajouté de l'eau, pour le « vin aigrelet, de basse qualité », que je connais surtout dans l'expression familière « c'est de la piquette » dans le sens de « c'est une chose négligeable, sans valeur » (TLFi).

---

- La *brioche* ou la *croûte de pâté* a-t-elle une connotation
  (négative) de « piquette (de la viennoiserie etc.) » aujourd'hui ; le
  fait que la *brioche* puisse s'employer comme signifiant « bévue » le
  confirme-t-il ; linguistiquement parlant, laquelle de la *brioche* ou
  de la *croûte de pâté* a la meilleure « réputation » ?
- Peut-on présenter une paire de (noms ou termes de)
  viennoiseries/pâtisseries/boulangerie/mets/aliments et une paire (de noms ou termes) relatif à l'alcool ou œnologiques qui illustrent le haut et le bas de l'échelle des *connotations* (ou du sens) en français avec des exemples d'emplois qui l'étayent (on peut récupérer *brioche, croûte de pâté* et *piquette* au besoin) ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Il s'agirait plutôt des propos de *Victoire de France* : « Mais mon Dieu, s'ils pouvaient se résigner à manger de la croûte de pâté ! »,  « moins onéreuse que le pain », alors que « la pâte feuilletée n'était initialement pas conçue pour être consommée, mais seulement pour aider à la cuisson et à la conservation du pâté » (Wikipédia) ; voire même [antérieurs](http://www.histoire-fr.com/mensonges_histoire_pain_brioche_marie_antoinette.htm).</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La brioche semble avoir perdu toute connotation négative aujourd'hui. Il ne doit pas être aisé de trouver une citation de moins de cinquante ans utilisant *brioche* pour dire *bévue*.

Pour ce qui est de la "*croûte de pâté*", je n'avais jamais lu ou entendu cette expression avant aujourd'hui... Il est donc difficile de comparer. En cherchant j'ai bien évidemment trouvé l'expression **[croûte de pâté vaut bien pain](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JAuEnN7_rWUC&pg=PA404&lpg=PA404&dq=cro%C3%BBte%20de%20p%C3%A2t%C3%A9%20vaut%20bien%20pain&source=bl&ots=JDnZlsfxpg&sig=ACfU3U1rp8_n-Djpnt8aasQII4tzqbm3Cw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTnLOUpZDgAhVi8OAKHR2pDvQQ6AEwCnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=cro%C3%BBte%20de%20p%C3%A2t%C3%A9%20vaut%20bien%20pain&f=false)** dans la *nouvelle édition du dictionnaire de l'académie françoise* de... 1802.

Donc linguistiquement parlant, *la croûte de pâté* n'ayant aucune réputation récente il ne reste que la *brioche* pour avoir la meilleure réputation entre les deux.

Pour ce qui est de la paire d'aliments, et la paire d'alcools, représentant les deux opposés d'une échelle de connotations on a par exemple :

- merde - caviar
- piquette - nectar

Exemple d'emplois (bien que les emplois coulent de source, les exemples sont demandés dans la question) :

- *[C'est d'la merde](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuCRGsC9XhU)*
- *[C'est le caviar de la viande](http://www.leparisien.fr/liveafp-france/le-wagyu-caviar-de-viande-venu-du-japon-eleve-au-fin-fond-de-l-aisne-28-12-2008-355651.php)*
- *[C'est de la piquette](https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/ligue-1-ce-bordeaux-la-c-est-de-la-piquette-20-02-2011-1297490_26.php)*
- *[Un vrai nectar](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g642170-d1812759-i35379071-Le_Sud-Naoussa_Paros_Cyclades_South_Aegean.html)*